# select case with H2 database asking to group by column

Tags: sql, jdbc, h2, select-case

When I use HQL to query my database, this requests works fine and return the good data :

```
    select
    case 
        when activityjp0_.status<>'CLOSED' 
        and (activityjp0_.user_id is null) then 'UNASSIGNED' 
        else case 
            when activityjp0_.status<>'CLOSED' 
            and activityjp0_.deadline<CURRENT_DATE then 'OVERDUE' 
            else case 
                when activityjp0_.status='PENDING' then 'IN_PROGRESS' 
                else activityjp0_.status 
            end 
        end 
    end as col_0_0_,
    count(distinct activityjp0_.id) as col_1_0_ 
from
    activities activityjp0_ 
group by
    case 
        when activityjp0_.status<>'CLOSED' 
        and (activityjp0_.user_id is null) then 'UNASSIGNED' 
        else case 
            when activityjp0_.status<>'CLOSED' 
            and activityjp0_.deadline<CURRENT_DATE then 'OVERDUE' 
            else case 
                when activityjp0_.status='PENDING' then 'IN_PROGRESS' 
                else activityjp0_.status 
            end 
        end 
    end
```

When I use Criteria API to generate the SAME request, it gives :

```
    select
    case 
        when activityjp0_.status<>? 
        and (activityjp0_.user_id is null) then 'UNASSIGNED' 
        else case 
            when activityjp0_.status<>? 
            and activityjp0_.deadline<? then 'OVERDUE' 
            else case 
                when activityjp0_.status=? then 'IN_PROGRESS' 
                else activityjp0_.status 
            end 
        end 
    end as col_0_0_,
    count(distinct activityjp0_.id) as col_1_0_ 
from
    activities activityjp0_ 
group by
    case 
        when activityjp0_.status<>? 
        and (activityjp0_.user_id is null) then 'UNASSIGNED' 
        else case 
            when activityjp0_.status<>? 
            and activityjp0_.deadline<? then 'OVERDUE' 
            else case 
                when activityjp0_.status=? then 'IN_PROGRESS' 
                else activityjp0_.status 
            end 
        end 
    end
```

BUT this result in a JDBC error claiming :

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "ACTIVITYJP0_.USER_ID" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
```

select case when activityjp0_.status<>? and (activityjp0_.user_id is null) then 'UNASSIGNED' else case when activityjp0_.status<>? and activityjp0_.deadline? and (activityjp0_.user_id is null) then 'UNASSIGNED' else case when activityjp0_.status<>? and activityjp0_.deadline

If I replace the variables in the same generated query, and run it against my database (in h2 console) it runs with no error

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two very similar expressions:

```sql
    case 
        when activityjp0_.status<>? 
        and (activityjp0_.user_id is null) then 'UNASSIGNED' 
        else case 
            when activityjp0_.status<>? 
            and activityjp0_.deadline<? then 'OVERDUE' 
            else case 
                when activityjp0_.status=? then 'IN_PROGRESS' 
                else activityjp0_.status 
            end 
        end 
    end
```

But actually they aren't the same, because parameters (`?`) are all different; you have 4 parameters in the first expression and 4 additional parameters in the second one. You should use `group by col_0_0_` instead of `group by case … end` or you can use the same indexed (`?1`, `?2`, …) parameters in both expressions.

Comment: This sql is generated by hibernate (visible through format_sql=true property) from my criteria API code, so I cannot use ?1 ...
I am also unable to use the alias col_0_0_ as it is generated too.
I did a test with pure hql  & :refDate parameter which gives the same error
PS: pure HQL with no parameters (ie hard writing values) works well in H2 !

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't valid for H2 (and possibly for some other databases), Hibernate has many known issues with its grouped queries. Your issue looks like HHH-11513, but maybe it's a different one. The usual workaround is to use the Native Query feature of Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks clarification, It may be not a valid hql request. Since my code should work cross databases, I should not use native queries.
I think I'll just remove the group by clause and group the result in memory using Streams ..
It is weird that we can never do performance optimized requests using Hibernate.